# Derivative using the quotient rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$g(x) = \displaystyle\frac{x + 1}{(x + 2)^{10}}$

by the quotient rule I get

$
\begin{align}
g'(x) & = \displaystyle\frac{1.(x + 2)^{10} - 10.1.(x + 2)^9(x + 1)}{(x + 2)^{20}}\\
& = \displaystyle\frac{x + 2}{(x + 2)^{11}} - \frac{10.(x + 1)}{(x + 2)^{11}}
\\
& = \displaystyle\frac{-9x - 8}{(x + 2)^{11}}
\end{align}
$

my handbook however gives the answer as

$\displaystyle\frac{1 - 9x}{(x + 2)^{11}}$

I just can't see where I made a mistake

Comment: @Joe: $$\frac{(x+2)^{10}}{(x+2)^{20}}=\frac1{(x+2)^{10}}=\frac{x+2}{(x+2)^{11}}$$

Comment: Your answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is this: you did *nothing* wrong. The handbook is in error. [Here's confirmation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%28x%2B1%29%2a%28x%2B2%29%5E-10). [Also, there's this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=antiderivative+of+%281-9x%29%2a%28x%2B2%29%5E-11).

Comment: Best news I have had all night

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the handbook is wrong.  It seems as if the $10$ was not distributed to $(x+1)$ all the way after differentiating:
$$\dfrac{(x+2)^{10}-10(x+2)^9(x+1)}{(x+2)^{20}}=\dfrac{(x+2)^9[(x+2)-10(x+1)]}{(x+2)^{20}}=\dfrac{(-8-9x)}{(x+2)^{11}}$$
Since they did not distribute the $10$ all the way, they got $\dfrac{(1-9x)}{(x+2)^{11}}.$  So you are correct.